# There is a way to do a preview of a DWG/RFA file using Bitmap in C#?

Tags: c#, bitmap

Can you tell me if exists some tutorials or code which creates a preview from DWG or RFA file using Bitmap class in C# ?

Thank you

Comment: This may be useful - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156522/DXF-Import-NET-Read-and-View-AutoCAD-Format-Files

Comment: Hence the qualifier 'may', fair enough!